# Counting number of two pairs vs. full house

Tags: probability

I'm trying to count the number of ways to draw 1) two pairs in a 4 card hand, and; 2) a full house in a 5 card hand.

For 1) I have the expression $\binom{13}{2} \binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}$ corresponding to (1 committee of 2 ranks from 13 possible) * (1 committee of 2 from 4 possible) * (1 committee of 2 from 4 possible).

I reasoned 2) is pretty much the same as 1) but with the additional card in the 3-pair, so I wrote $\binom{13}{2} \binom{4}{3}\binom{4}{2}$ with $\binom{4}{3}$ corresponding to the 3-pair.  I was surprised to find out that while the expression for 1) is correct, the expression for 2) should be

$13 \cdot 12 \cdot \binom{4}{3} \cdot \binom{4}{2}$

If anyone can explain the difference, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the two pairs, the pairs are interchangeable.  When you write $13 \choose 2$ you are choosing the ranks without paying attention to the order you choose them in.  For the full house it matters which order you choose them in because the first will be the three of a kind while the second will be the pair.  The product $13 \cdot 12$ is precisely twice $13 \choose 2$ for the order selection.

Comment: I get it now.  Thanks Ross!